# Window Phone 7 and MVVM, Loaded event of a Page

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, mvvm

Hi, I have a problem using the MVVM pattern after I instantiate my view model in this way:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <local:DetailVM x:Key="DetailVM"/>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

How do I know when this Page is Loaded?

Comment: Do you mean "Know when the page is loaded in my ViewModel"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3062) and add an event trigger that triggers a command in your viewmodel.

include

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

in your xmlns includes, and then add a trigger for the `Loaded` event.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

The `LoadCommand` is simply a property that returns an `ICommand`. You should of course either set the DataContext of the page to your viewmodel, or set the source of the binding to the one in your resources.